# Send a dynamic request body in Postman for subsequent request

Tags: json, api, postman

Using Post I have created a request and I have stored a response in one variable.

```
"{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"subject\":\"maths}"
```

I want to update the subject value as Using put

"{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"subject\":\"English}"

Test script request 1:

```
var response=JSON.parse(responseBody};

Pm.globals.set("variable",JSON.stringify(response);
```

In the pre-request script for request 2:

```
var request=JSON.parse(pm.globals.get("variable"));

pm.globals.set("req_body",JSON.stringify(request));
```

In the body:

```
{{req_body}}
```